# SQL command to update re order levels and quantities based on stock sold year to date or between two dates

Tags: sql

I tried to put the following into my Database Utility in IQ Retail, but it did not work.

```
update Stock
set MIN_LVL=UnitsYearToDate/5
set ORD_QUANT=UnitsYearToDate/5*3
where (only using one of the following)
REGULAR_SU='xxx'
or
SUBDEPARTM='xxx'
or
CODE between 'xxx' and 'xxx'
```

I get this error

> "DBISAM Engine Error # 11949 SQL parsing error - Expected end of
>   statement but instead found set in UPDATE SQL statement at line 3,
>   column 1"

I have no programming knowledge, I am just trying to self help because of my remote location. Any advice on how I can update minimum order levels and order quantities in specific batches for about 12000 stock items would be appreciated.

I am using the packaged database utility in IQ Retail software.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - you don't need to define set multiple times, just use one set and define multiple columns using comma (,)

```
update Stock set MIN_LVL=UnitsYearToDate/5,ORD_QUANT=UnitsYearToDate/5*3 
where REGULAR_SU='xxx' or SUBDEPARTM='xxx' or CODE between 'xxx' and 'xxx'
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get an error, this time  "DBISAM Engine Error # 11949 SQL parsing error - Expected column name but instead found ORD_QUANT in UPDATE SQL statement at line 2, column 32"

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is worng. Multiple `SET` must be separated by comma:

```
update Stock
set MIN_LVL=UnitsYearToDate/5, ORD_QUANT=UnitsYearToDate/5*3
where 
REGULAR_SU='xxx'
or
SUBDEPARTM='xxx'
or
CODE between 'xxx' and 'xxx'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get an error, this time "DBISAM Engine Error # 11949 SQL parsing error - Expected column name but instead found ORD_QUANT in UPDATE SQL statement at line 2, column 32"

Comment: @SeanWaller isn't ORD_QUANT a column in your table?

Comment: I tried this simple command - update Stock
set MIN_LVL=1, ORD_QUAN=10
where 
REGULAR_SU='800165' - which worked fine. So the issue seems to be the "units year to date", could it be this value is stored in another table, maybe StockHist?

Comment: @SeanWaller How should I know it? I do not see any of your tables

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the syntax is incorrect and when you have multiple SET you will need to separate them with a comma. DBISAM order of execution can be different you will need to note that as well. Refer to this documentation for an [UPDATE Statement](https://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=viewtopic&id=dbisam4&product=delphi&version=7&topic=update_statement)

Try this code

`UPDATE Stock SET MIN_LVL = 2, ORD_QUAN = 3 FROM Stock WHERE SUBDEPARTM = '0002';`